# How to include java packages from another project

Tags: java, package, project, reusability

I might be thinking of this incorrectly, I'm coming from a visual studio background.  Here is the problem I have.  I have 3 projects, ProgramA, ProgramB, and ProgramBase.  Each exist in a separate Java project, ProgramBase contains common functionality that I want both ProgramA and ProgramB to use.  How do I achieve this?  All I can find are examples of all three being packages within the same project.  what happens if ProgramA is developed for one company, and ProgramB is another company, and ProgramBase is some common code I've developed?  Surely I don't have to have ProgramA and ProgramB in the same project to be able to access the package(s) of ProgramBase?

If I were doing this in visual studio, ProgramA would be one solution, ProgramB would be another solution, and ProgramBase would be a project which is included into each solution.  If I do this in java, because the package has to be under to src directory, I don't know how both projects can include it?

Thank you for any help or resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `eclipse` ide, you can do something like 
go to `ProgramA -> right click Properties -> Java Build Path -> Project -> Add`

[image]

If you using command line to compile , just do `javac -classpath <location of your ProgramBase Jar file`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jar-file that ProgramA and ProgramB can both include.